# Determine the size of an object from an aeriel photo

Tags: aerial-photography

Given:

I shoot from 1,000 feet ASL
I used Canon 1000D with 500mm telephoto lens

Question:

How can I measure or find the size of an object that i shoot using the following data?
Can you show me the formula?

Comment: You also need to know the size of the sensor in your camera (22,2 mm x 14,8 mm Canon 1000D) to get the imaged size of the subject in your photo.